# VB.NET Listbox System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Image: http://i.epvpimg.com/FTSsf.png

So, i have this code for my Private Messages app:

```
Private Sub ReplyToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ReplyToolStripMenuItem.Click

  Try
            If Not ListBoxAdv1.SelectedItem.ToString = Nothing Then
                Dim sp = ListBoxAdv1.SelectedItem.ToString()


                cru = sp.Substring(0, sp.IndexOf(":"))

                datee = sp.Substring(0, sp.IndexOf(")"))
                datee = datee.Replace("(", "")



                Dim us As String = sp.Substring(21, sp.IndexOf(":"))
                Dim pmo As String = us.Substring(0, us.IndexOf(":")).Trim
                Dim pm As New new_pm
                pm.own = pmo
                pm.Show()

            End If
        Catch ex As System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try



    End Sub
```

The problem is with the first item, it gives me error "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string." only if listbox contains more than 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

The code makes a lot of assumptions here:

```
cru = sp.Substring(0, sp.IndexOf(":"))
datee = sp.Substring(0, sp.IndexOf(")"))

Dim us As String = sp.Substring(21, sp.IndexOf(":"))
Dim pmo As String = us.Substring(0, us.IndexOf(":"))
```

Are these strings always guaranteed to be greater than these lengths?  And to contain these characters?  The exception says no, they're not.

For example, if `sp` is of length `0` then there is no index `0` (no first character), so the first line of code will fail.  If it's not at least 22 characters long then the third line will fail.  If it doesn't contain a `":"` then the first line will fail.  And so on.

Since you don't have a lot of control over the content of the strings, you'll need to put in some error checking and then handle with some measure of business logic the edge cases.  For example, where you have something like this:

```
cru = sp.Substring(0, sp.IndexOf(":"))
```

You may first want to ensure `sp` has what you think it has.  Something like:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sp) Then
    ' an error condition, notify the user perhaps?
End If
```

and/or something like:

```
If sp.IndexOf(":") < 0 Then
    ' an error condition, notify the user perhaps?
End If
```

Before processing the strings, ensure they meet the assumptions made by the code.  If they don't meet those assumptions, then the code can't process them and something else must be done.  (Which could be as simple as just displaying a message to the user, or even silently ignoring and continuing.)

Comment: When I call msgbox(sp) it shows up the pm, and msgbox(sp.lenght) shows up the lenght of the pm, for example, 34

Comment: @AlexandruToma: When you step through this in a debugger, which line throws the actual exception?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  Don't assume the strings are correct, clearly one of them is not.

Comment: Dim us As String = sp.Substring(21, sp.IndexOf(":")), and the lenght of sp is 34

Comment: @AlexandruToma: And what is the *value* of `sp`?  Does it contain a `":"` character?  The runtime isn't just making up an exception, it happens for a reason.

Comment: I just want to add that you need to invoke `GetItemText` to ensure that you get the text representation of a specified item as seen on screen. `Dim sp As String = ListBoxAdv1.GetItemText(ListBoxAdv1.SelectedItem)`

Comment: @AlexandruToma: Honestly, that sounds more like an assumption than debugging information.  An exception wouldn't be thrown if the input met the criteria.  So either the entire .NET runtime is fundamentally broken (and therefore non-deterministic) on your computer (which is unlikely), or your logic is incorrect (which is more likely).  Step through the code in a debugger.  When you get to the line which throws the exception, examine the runtime values.  Use the command window in the debugger to examine the results of your inline operations (`sp.IndexOf(":")`).  Nobody here can do this for you.

Comment: Is something strange, because, if listbox contains less than 2 items, no error